# GTK and 4 way handshake

Tags: brute-force, wpa2

GTK is transferred at 3 message.

https://www.wifi-professionals.com/2019/01/4-way-handshake

What is for GTK key in 4 way handshake while PTK exists?

Answer (score 1):

"Group temporal key is used to encrypt all broadcast and multicast traffic between an access point and multiple client devices. GTK is the key which is shared between all client devices associated with 1 access point."

"Pairwise Transient key is used to encrypt all unicast traffic between a client station and the access point. PTK is unique between a client station and access point."

https://www.wifi-professionals.com/2019/01/4-way-handshake

Multicast is used to send messages to multiple devices while unicast is used for point-to-point traffic. Every client/station connected to the AP shares the same GTK, but all have a unique PTK.